# Cartier Divisor corresponds on $X$ to $(U_i,f_i)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme. $\mathcal K $ be the sheaf of total quotients of $X$. $\mathcal K^*$ be the sheaf corresponding sheaf of invertible elements of $\mathcal K$. So $\mathcal O_X^*$ is a subsheaf $\mathcal K^*$.

An  Cartier Divisor on $X$ is by definition a global section of the sheaf
 ${\mathcal K^*} /  {\mathcal O_X^*}$.

Now I want to prove that giving an global section of ${\mathcal K^*} /  {\mathcal O_X^*}$ is same as providing the following data:  $\mathrm{collection}{(U_i,f_i)}$ such that $f_i \in \Gamma (U_i, \mathcal K^*)$, where ${U_i}'s$ covers X and $f_i/f_j \in \Gamma(U_i \cap U_j, \mathcal O_X^*)$.

Comment: What've you tried out?

Comment: Repeat the construction of a quotient sheaf.

Comment: I have done it. I have the answer. I will write it soon. I thought, I should write down the formal proof here.

Comment: Basically one has to use the fact: A global section of ${\mathcal K^*} /  {\mathcal O_X^*}$ is a function from $s: X\rightarrow  {\prod_{p\in X} \widehat{(\frac{\mathcal K^*} {\mathcal O_X^*})}}_p$ where $\widehat{(\frac{\mathcal K^*} {\mathcal O_X^*})}$ is just the  presheaf such that for any $x\in X$ (i) $s(x)=\widehat{(\frac{\mathcal K^*} {\mathcal O_X^*})}_x$ and (ii) For any $x\in X$ there exists an open set $U_x$ of X containing $x$ and an element $t\in\widehat{\frac{\mathcal K^*} {\mathcal O_X^*}}(U) $such that  for any  $q\in U$  ,    $t|_q=s(q)$

Comment: The sheaf $\mathcal K$ is the sheaf of rational functions on X. Its relation to total fields of quotients is [more subtle](http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?type=pdf&rid=ensmat-001:1979:25::101&subp=hires) than one might think, even if "one" is Grothendieck...

Comment: @Georges: Thank you for the article. It is illuminating.